# Python: Calling a method from the importing class

Tags: python, oop, class

Well, I guess that my question was already asked before, but I don't really know which terms to use to search for it, so apologize if this is a duplicate.

My question is how to call a method from the class which creates an instance of the current class? For example we have:

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "This is a text in First class"
        self.second = Second()

class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        print "How to show self.text from First?"
```

The way I'm doing this right now is to pass `self` from class `First` as an argument when initiating the `Second` class, `self.second = Second(self)` but I'm not sure if this is the right way. Also I found that it this could be possible by making `Second` a subclass of `First`, but I'm still not sure if this is the right way.

Could you help me with an answer?
Thank you

Comment: if i understand your question right, you're looking to inherit into Second from First

Comment: 1) What is your actual problem? For arbitrary classes any solution is fine. 2) Think of objects, not classes.

Comment: @AdityaSihag - I want to access properties and methods from First in Seconds. For example, let's say that some action in Second needs to call a callback in First.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "This is a text in First class"
        self.second = Second(self)

class Second:
    def __init__(self, first):
        self.first = first
        print "How to show self.text from First?"
        print self.first.text
```

Objects that know each other in this way and use each others attributes, I fear, are likely to violate [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) or make it hard to distinguish each other.
And to distinguish them is very important for writing "good" classes.
So handle it with care!

Other solution: pass text:

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "This is a text in First class"
        self.second = Second(self.text)

class Second:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        print "How to show self.text from First?"
        print self.text
```

This is also quite ok.
I would like it more than the first solution.
But when there are more arguments to come, text1, text2, text3, ... than this could be a new object.

```
class First(object):
    @property
    def text(self):
        "get text from self.second"
        return self.second.text

    def __init__(self):
        self.second = Second("This is a text in First class")
        print self.text

class Second:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        print "How to show self.text from First?"
        print self.text
```

I think this is also quite a good solution for synchronising the text.
But I can not think of an example where I really needed it.

Comment: This is the way I'm doing it right now, and my question was actually if this is the good way or there's a better way to achieve this.